# Linq returns Nullable object must have a value because some columns are null

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a linq query in a loop. I am querying by date range, at some date range everything runs and returns fine. But at some other date range, I got "Nullable object must have a value.

I discovered that some values are null in the tables

Some of the answers on StackOverflow suggested ignoring when the columns are empty.

But I my case I cant ignore it because a column is null.

Here is my query

```
                var cargoActivityResponse = await (from ca in context.CargoActivities.Where(cargo => cargo.ReservationId == task[i].BerReservationId)
                                            from cargo in context.CargoActivityTypes
                                            where ca.ActivityTypeId == cargo.Id
                                            from category in context.CargoCategories
                                            where ca.CargoCategoryId == category.Id
                                            from routes in context.TradeRoutes
                                            where ca.TradeRouteId == routes.Id
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                ActivityType = cargo.Name,
                                                Cargo = category.Name,
                                                TradeRoute = routes.Name,
                                                Quantity_Num = ca.Quantity_Num,
                                                Quantity_UOM = ca.Quantity_UOM,
                                            }).ToListAsync();
```

How can return everything even if some column are null or returning null?

Stacktrace if that will be helpfull

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_NoValue()
   at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
   at Port.Info.Business.Billings.<BillingData>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\john\source\repos\Port.Info\PortInfo\Business\Billings.cs:line 155
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Port.Info.Controllers.BillingsController.<BillingData>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\john\source\repos\Port.Info\PortInfo\Controllers\BillingsController.cs:line 49
```

Comment: Did you create db schema via code-first?

Comment: Yes, code-first

Comment: 1) `task[I]`, can be null 2) Is there any reason to do that in loop? You can retrieve everything via single query.

Comment: I already have a query that already returns a list, then I am using that list to get another list.  @SvyatoslavDanyliv task[i].BerReservationId is not null

Comment: it is not a reason to run a loop. `context.CargoActivities.Where(cargo => task.Select(x => x.BerReservationId).Contains(cargo.ReservationId))`

Comment: `task[I]` can be null, not property access. Anyway, post callstack.

Comment: Not sure, but probably there is closure problem. Try to assign `task[I]` to local variable and use in query value from local variable.

Comment: The anonymous type inherits its types from the properties in the projection, but some should be nullable types. If, for example, `ca.Quantity_Num` is an `int` but the query has null values for some rows you have to convert it to `int?` explicitly: `Quantity_Num = (int?)ca.Quantity_Num`.

Comment: I just discovered now that ```Quantity_Num = ca.Quantity_Num,``` is returning null

Comment: Well, there you go.

Comment: Yes, I was able to fix that